# rabbitmq AMQP::consume()

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, queueing

AMQP function consume() is a blocking function with a callback,
Is it possible to set a timeout for consume() function, so after specific amount of time it doesn't block anymore and the code execution completes ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, here's how:

```php
$amqp = new AMQPConnection($your_connection_params);
$amqp->setTimeout($seconds);
```

Then when you call consume() on a queue, if no messages arrive within the timeout period, an AMQPException will be thrown from consume() with the message, "Resource temporarily unavailable".  If you ever break out of consume() or hit a timeout, be sure to call cancel() on the queue object to properly reset the consumer.  In order to do this, you need to generate a globally unique consumer tag and pass it in as an undocumented, third parameter to consume:

```php
$tag = uniqid() . microtime(true);
$queue->consume($callback, $flags, $tag);
$queue->cancel($tag);
```

That way, you can call consume() again later without weird issues that will make your head spin.

Comment: FYI, I'm using the pecl amqp module, version 1.0.9.  I tried upgrading to the latest version recently and my code completely broke.  But the method I described above is working properly with amqp-1.0.9 and rabbitmq 3.1.3.

Comment: Ran into this scenario today and your answer lead me in the right direction. The `setTimeout` method has been deprecated in favour of the `setReadTimeout`. Also make sure to capture the `AMQPConnectionException` exception that consume throws when you timeout. AMQP version 1.4